# The Registry Key For 'Notify Me When (adapter) Has Limited Or No Connectivity

Tags: windows-xp, windows-registry, windows-networking

I'm trying to script some configuration parameters for network adapters and would like to enable the 'Notify me when this connection has limited or no connectivity' option. (On the connection properties dialogue).

Does anyone know where/ what key this is in the registry? (Win XP SP3)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found it I think:

`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Network\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\{** ADAPTER GUID **}\Connection\IpCheckingEnabled]`